# Button has to be clicked twice in Android Studio to work (different from other peoples issues)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

I have 2 edit texts and both of them are linked to their respective image buttons. When I click the buttons and use the input from edit text it only works once I press it for the second time. Basically I have a big value and any number I put in the edit text is subtracted from the big value once the button is pressed.

I have another button on the same activity that takes you to the settings activity but that one works perfectly fine, I do not know why these 2 buttons require double tap.

**XML Code:**

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/plusCal"
    android:layout_width="38dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/plus" />
```

**Activity Code:**

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
//create private ImageButton Object
private ImageButton setting_button;
TextView Cremaining, Premaining;
EditText MinusCal, MinusPro;
ImageButton plusCal, plusPro;

String calData, proData;
SharedPreferences prefs;

int calint, proint, Calinput, ProInput;
String Result;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    calData = prefs.getString("Cal_Total","0");
    proData = prefs.getString("Pro_Total","0");


    //retrieve TxtView using findviewbyID
    Cremaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RemainingCal);
    Premaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RemainingPro);

    //Retrieve EditButton using findviewbyID

    MinusCal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditCal) ;
    MinusPro = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditPro);

    //Retrieve Button using findViewbyID
    plusCal = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.plusCal);
    plusPro = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.plusProtein);



    //Set Protein and Calories either from settings or update from result
        Cremaining.setText(calData);
        Premaining.setText(proData);

    plusCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            //Subtract Calories from Input calories, then set total to calData and save and set text
            Calinput = Integer.parseInt(MinusCal.getText().toString());
            calint = Integer.parseInt(calData);
            calint -= Calinput;
            calData = String.valueOf(calint);
            editor.putString("Cal_Total", calData);
            calData = prefs.getString("Cal_Total","0");
            Cremaining.setText(calData);




            editor.apply();

        }
                                   });
```

Ignore the formatting and redundant variables, I aim to clean up the code once I have the issue working, same goes with any error handling (try catches)

UPDATE: I figured it out:
The editor, I am using .apply() instead of commit and I am using it late in the call of execution, so i set  the value, save it to shared preferences, and then recall the shared preferences without commiting in the right flow which causes it too pick up the old value.

Comment: Can you try changing the `android:srcCompat` to only `android:src` ? In the XML

Comment: please put a log in onClick method and check. May be it goes to on click but your code not work.

Comment: code is working in on click, since the operation intended is working just takes 2 presses every single time

Comment: Hey guys, I figured it out, the editor, I am using .apply() instead of commit and I am using it late in the call of execution, so i set  the value, save it to shared preferences, and then recall the shared preferences without commiting in the right flow which causes it too pick up the old value and make me click twice.

Answer (score 1):

When you edit the editText, that view has focus. So the first tap will make it lose focus (the edit caret will disappear) and the second tap can go to the button or any other views.

You can do
`editText.setOnFocusChangeListener` and then if the `focus == false` you can run the action you want.

Or you can do `editText.addTextChangedListener()` and override the methods you want. 
 You can trigger the action you want in there and as the user enter a value, you can automatically do the calculation. No need for the buttons in this case.

Or you can `editText.setOnKeyListener()` and override `onKey()` and detect when the enter key is tapped do something like this:

```
if ((keyevent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
{
 //perform the action you want
}
```

Comment: Hey man, so this I do not think will work, since I checked and it happens every time, I tap it twice, it does the work and it keeps making tap twice even if I do not click edit text.

Comment: Hey man, I figured it out, the editor, I am using .apply() instead of commit and I am using it late in the call of execution, so i set  the value, save it to shared preferences, and then recall the shared preferences without commiting in the right flow which causes it too pick up the old value.